How to merge a new SSD into my existing partitions for both Windows and Linux Mint
I want to get another SSD for my new PC because I'm running out of space, I have a dual boot Linux Mint 21.3 and Windows 11 Pro and I'd like to know how could I merge that new SSD into these existing partitions.
Is it even possible? Could I use the new SSD separated into Windows partition and Linux partition for things other than just storing files?

"Partitions" are data structures on physical disks, so its not possible for a "partition" to span multiple disks (unless you use special hardware to create a RAID array, which you clearly do not have, and creating one now would destroy all your data). As such you cannot add space to the disk partitions you already have.

Thank you. So what are my options about expanding the space when I put a new SSD in? Can I at least split it so I can use one for Windows (NTFS I guess?) and one for Mint?

There might not be any reason to split the SSD. For example, if partitioned NTFS, both Linux and Windows can use it. It can be used to share data, or even some applications. On this PC, I run IrfanView in (native) Windows, and also under wine in Ubuntu. As long as no operating system files are on it, it should be both readable and writable in both OS's.

I still have trust issues using NTFS with Linux, except in the most cursory of use-cases (preferably ones where not a lot of writing occurs).

@FrankThomas Indeed, if you have Linux only you shouldn't be using NTFS but this scenario is a dual-boot so, in the event of logical errors, the filesystem can be corrected within Windows. Important: disable the Fast Startup "feature" in Windows when sharing a NTFS (or other Microsoft typical filesystems) partition with a second OS.

@DrMoishePippik I like this idea. And would it work if I partitioned the SSD into two different disks that I could 'mount' and one is only for Windows, the other only for Linux, so the files don't mix? Also, do these mount automatically or do I have to mount them every time?

You can partition your drive any way you want, that's not the problem. The problem is you don't really understand what you're doing and consequently what you're asking here. There are configurations that make sense and other that don't. Linux will always "see" anything (you think is) "only for Windows" and it may or may not automatically mount it; Windows OTOH will only "see" partitions with filesystems it recognizes (e.g. NTFS, exFAT, ...) and by default it auto-mounts everything.

Yes, you can create 2 or more partitions on the SSD. If you wish to use one exclusively for Linux and another for Windows, that is your choice, too. As for automatically mounting a drive at startup, it is easy: https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup . If you plan to prevent Windows from mounting the Linux partition, format it ext4, or other file system not native to Windows.

@DrMoishePippik thank you so much, this is very useful!

Your best option is to use a cloning/moving tool to move one of the OS to the new ssd.  Then expand the corresponding partition to file the whole disk.
You will likely have to adjust the boot loader for the new configuration, but once that is done it does work.
Now linux can mount a windows NTFS file system, and support is much better since paragon software contribute there driver to the kernel.  However, windows does not natively support the linux filesystems.
There maybe a few 3rd parties you could buy a driver from, but I haven't had any experience with these software packages.

Would this mean that one of my operative systems would be moved to the new SSD to entirely take up that space? Apologies if I didn't understand.

Yes.  It is a multiple step process.  1. Copy the selected OS to the new SSD  2.  Delete the partition from the original drive.  3.  Expand the orginal drive file system.  4.  Expand the file system on the new drive.  You can use software like gparted to partition your drive.  In gparted changes don't take effect until you hit the apply button, it may take an hour or more depending on how much data you have.  The step is to adjust the boot loader so it knows where the OS was moved to.  It would be help to see a screen capture of disk management tool in windows.

@cybernard Someone asking this question (and the first comment here) has no idea about "adjusting the bootloader". Your suggestion here is perfectly fine - albeit arguably unnecessary - for advanced users but NOT for someone asking this question.

@ChanganAuto  I rarely change boot loaders so I don't have much experience in this area.  Virtual Machines and SBC like the Raspberry Pi make dual booting in this manner something I rarely do.  So I intentionally decided to not give any advice on boot loaders instead of giving wrong advice.
